# An equation of superior degree, with a very high degree. How is it possible to solve it?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was watching videos on Youtube, when I stopped to watch one in particular that was about Galois and Abel. In this video is explained that:
"There isn't any general mathematical formula that works for every equation in any degree and it will never exist (Abel explained that). Then, Galois created a rule that says which features the coefficients of any equation in any degree need to create a formula that could solve it. So not every equation larger than the fifth degreee equation has a formula, but thanks to Galois we know which of them have one and we can create their formulas."

So I have a question: what if I want to solve a 47th degree equation? How do I solve it if I don't know his formula? (I suppose that we haven't discovered the 47th degree formula yet)

Comment: You use numerical methods.

Comment: Depends on your equation. If it is $x^{47}=2$, we know all solutions without numerical methods.

Comment: What Abel and Galois say is not that the formula for degree (not *grade*)  $47$ has not been discovered yet, but that such a formula doesn't exist, unless the equation satisfies some specific (and highly non-trivial) conditions.

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer. and sorry for "grade" mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: Dietrich Burde, I didn't want to include in my question that type of equation (where the solution can be found easily). I think that The type of equation I was talking about is called "Polynomial Equations"

Answer (score 0):

In general for polynomials of degree $5$ or higher you cannot analytically find a general solution. Instead we resort to numerical methods, for example Newton's method, or the Bisection method, or fixed point iteration, etc.

This a typical topic in a numerical analysis / methods course.